# can not debug VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Code = "Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) " & vbCrLf
```

After adding above code I can not use Breakpoint. It gives me message warning

"Can't enter break mode at this time"

Options are "Continue,End & Help" is enable

But "Debug" is disable

Even if there is an error in code. It show error code and message and the only options are 
End  & Help 
Debug is disabled.

Comment: can you show some more of your code that we could understand wider context